# Язык Си. Не могу сделать задачу без использования вещественных типов данных

Tags: c, математика

**Задача:**

"В стандартный поток ввода подаются натуральные числа N и k через пробел, причём N не больше 1 миллиарда, а k не больше 100. Найти значение дроби 1/N, которая будем иметь k знаков после запятой. Нельзя использовать вещественные типы данных. Вывести ответ в стандартный поток вывода."

Пример ввода 1:
10 1

Вывод:
0.1

Пример ввода 2:
52 5

Вывод:
0.01923

Пример ввода 3:
1733 50

Вывод:
0.00057703404500865551067512983266012694748990190421

Помогите, пожалуйста, выполнить лабораторную работу **на языке Си**.

**Нельзя использовать float и double**

Мой код с использованием вещественного типа данных(пытался понять, как выводить n-ое кол-во знаков после запятой):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void main(void)
{
    int n, k;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    float a = 1.00 / n;
    printf("%.*f\n", k, a);

}
```

Попробовал сделать:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long d = 1;
    int n, k, i, c, first;
    int a[k];
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
    {
        d *= 10;
        c = d / 10;
        a[i] = c;
        d = d % n;
    }
    first = 1 / n;
    printf("%d.%d", first, a)
}
```

Всем спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Весь смысл задания - заставить вас придумать этот алгоритм. Работать он должен так же, как вы бы на бумаге столбиком делили.

Comment: `void main(void)` - признак плохо выбранного учебного курса по C.

Comment: Само задание - прекрасно! Решите сами - получите удовольствие.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, этот плохо выбранный курс - университет))

Comment: Университет сам по себе не гарантирует качество всего что происходит под его крышей. Я учился в университете и преподаю в университете - с предметом знаком. Курс сдайте как полагается, а C надо учить по нормальным источникам. Теперь к задаче - вам нужно реализовать деление столбиком. Вполне по силам студенту университета.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Намечаю решение. Держим два числа (типа `long long` во избежание переполнений) — делимое (`D`, изначально 1) и делитель (`N`). Записываем на вывод `0.`. А дальше цикл из `k` итераций —

1. Умножаем `D` на 10, делим *нацело* на `N`, результат — одна цифра, пишем ее на вывод.
2. Присваиваем `D` остаток от деления `D` на `N`.
3. Переходим к шагу 1.

Собственно, все. После столь подробно расписанного алгоритма написать эти 5 строк решения — раз плюнуть...

**Update**

Ну, раз таки не плюнуть...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long D = 1, N, k;
    scanf("%llu %llu",&N,&k);
    printf("%llu.",D/N);
    D %= N;
    for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        D *= 10;
        printf("%llu",D/N);
        D %= N;
    }
}
```

Никаких нулей не наблюдается: https://ideone.com/HNLrwT

В *вашем добавленном* коде...

```
int n, k, i, c, first;
int a[k];
scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
```

Скажите, память для какого количества элементов вы выделяете в массиве `a`? Вы же их выделяете, когда значение `k` неизвестно, вы его не считали... Говорить после этой грубой ошибки о том, что выводит программа, смысла не имеет...

Comment: "Записываем на вывод 0.".  А если `N = 1`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну не придирайтесь :), очевидно же...

Comment: @Harry ваш алгоритм мне понятен, но в какой-то момент теряется точность. Например, с последним примером входных данных из задачи выводит  не "0.00057703404500865551067512983266012694748990190421", а "0.00057703402126207947731018066406250000000000000000". Решая своим методом, у меня получался такой же ответ, но так быть не должно.

Comment: @artemas, вы что-то перепутали. Этот метод не может терять точность, он вычислит любое количество цифр результата точно. Добавьте ваш новый код в вопрос. Если сделаете, я покажу свое решение.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, хорошо, добавил

Comment: Ну что ж, смотрите дополненный ответ...

Answer (score 3):

Я доработал ваш последний вариант. Массив не нужен, цифры печатаются как только они вычислены. Алгоритм деления в столбик:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, k;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);

    printf("%d.", 1 / n);
    int r = 1 % n;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        r *= 10;
        printf("%d", r / n);
        r %= n;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c 
>
> $ echo 10 1 | ./a.out 
> 0.1
>
> $ echo 52 5 | ./a.out 
> 0.01923
>
> $ echo 1733 50 | ./a.out 
> 0.00057703404500865551067512983266012694748990190421
>
> $ echo 1 3 | ./a.out 
> 1.000
> ```

Answer (score 1):

main(void) допускается. https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-main-Function что бы там не говорили выше.

`int a[k];` - какого размера массив? Инициализация этой переменной происодит после её использования. Это ошибка.
А также `int a[k];` - если k не константа времени компиляции, то это ошибка в широком смысле. В С99 есть массивы переменной длинны, но их работоспособность нужно проверять для каждого компилятора. Правильнее выделять память с помощью динамических функций.

`i` - зачем она объявлена за пределами цикла правильнее `for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++)`

`printf("%d.%d", &first, &a)` - нет точки запятой и ты передаёшь функции адреса, а не фактические параметры.

`a[i] = c;`  - здесь массив ты заполняешь сырыми данными, то есть бинарным представлением чисел. Но ведь ты хочешь его вывести как строку, я подразумеваю.

Давай переменным понятные имена.

Не указывай переменные в одну строку как здесь `int n, k, i, c, first;`. это не читаемо.

Старайся с пользователем и с самим собой вести диалог, это помогает не запутаться и проверить введенные значения.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    long long d = 1;
    int n = 0;
    int k = 0;

    printf("input: [n] [k]\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    printf("check: %d %d \n", n, k);

    char  floor;
    char *fractional = (char*)malloc(sizeof (char) * (k + 1));

    floor = ((1 / n) % 10)  + '0';

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        d *= 10;
        fractional[i] = (d/n) + '0';
        d %= n;
    }

    fractional[k+1] = '\0';

    printf("result: %c.%s\n", floor, fractional);

    free(fractional);
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: И ко всем вашим поучениям -- `sizeof(char)` тождественно равен +1 (для начального поощрения)

Comment: Где допускается `void main()`?!! Даже GCC с его вечными расширениями и то не допускает. По вашей же ссылке четко написано: **However, you cannot specify that it has a return type other than int.**!

Comment: Из вашей ссылки: `The return type for main is always int` Похоже, вы обратили внимание на аргументы, а не на возвращаемое значение. И ссылаться лучше на [стандарт](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function), а не на описание одного из компиляторов

Comment: Виноват, обратил внимание только на аргументы.

Comment: @Harry, тем не менее `#include <unistd.h>  void main () {write(1, "Hello\n", 6); }` у меня в `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` скомпилоровалось и отработало (я, честно говоря, не ожидал, думал что-то вроде -nostdlib и кучу слов для линкера придется прикручивать, но и так gcc съел и не подавился)

Comment: @avp Это он может, что и говорить — наруш... эээ... расширить собственную документацию... :)